# Trigonometry Problem Solving Pls Help!!!

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving

Observers at $P$ and $Q$ are located on the side of a hill that is inclined $32$ degrees to the horizontal. The observer at $P$ determines the angle of elevation to a hot air balloon to be $62$ degrees. At the same instant, the observer at $Q$ measures the angle of elevation to the balloon to be $71$ degrees. If $P$ is $60 $ m down the the hill from $Q$, find the distance from Q to the balloon.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: I don't know how to use the Law Of Sines for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Draw a picture and label the angles of elevation and the known distances.  Then, if you want to use the law of sines, you would apply $\frac{a}{\sin A}=\frac{b}{\sin B}=\frac{c}{\sin C}$, but don't be too quick to rush into using the law of sines.  The nice part about trig is that once you draw a picture and see what you are actually trying to find, you may be able to use several easy methods to find it!  But again, definitely start by drawing a picture!!!

Comment: You can use \sin x to generate $\sin x$ instead.

Comment: Sorry about that.  fixed.  :)

Comment: Thanks! Your answer really helped.

Comment: Got the correct answer, which is about 191.77 m.

Comment: very good!  Did drawing a picture help?

Comment: Yes! Thanks you very much!